# How to run Apache beam write to big query based on conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read values from Google pubsub and Google storage and put those values into big query based on count conditions i.e., if the values exists, then it should not insert the value, else it can insert a value.

My code looks like this:

```
p_bq = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options1)

logging.info('Start')

"""Pipeline starts. Create creates a PCollection from what we read from Cloud storage"""
test = p_bq | beam.Create(data)

"""The pipeline then reads from pub sub and then combines the pub sub with the cloud storage data"""
BQ_data1 = p_bq | 'readFromPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
    'mytopic') |  beam.Map(parse_pubsub, param=AsList(test))
```

where 'data' is the value from Google storage and reading from pubsub is the value from Google Analytics. Parse_pubsub returns 2 values: one is the dictionary and the other is count (which states the value is present or not in the table)

```
count=comparebigquery(insert_record)
return (insert_record,count)
```

How to provide condition to big query insertion since the value is in Pcollection

---

New edit:

```
class Process(beam.DoFn):

def process1(self, element, trans):
    if element['id'] in trans:
        # Emit this short word to the main output.
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('present',element)
    else:
        # Emit this word's long length to the 'above_cutoff_lengths' output.
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(
            'absent', present)

test1 = p_bq | "TransProcess" >> beam.Create(trans)
```

where trans is the list

```
BQ_data2 = BQ_data1 | beam.ParDo(Process(),trans=AsList(test1)).with_outputs('present','absent')
present_value=BQ_data2.present
absent_value=BQ_data2.absent
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
beam.Filter(lambda_function)
```

after the beam.Map step to filter out elements that return False when passed to the **lambda_function**.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the *PCollection* in a *ParDo* function using [Additional-outputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs) based on a condition.

Don't forget to provide output tags to the *ParDo* function `.with_outputs()`

And when writing elements of a *PCollection* to a specific output, use `.TaggedOutput()`

Then you select the *PCollection* you need and write it to BigQuery.

Comment: Hi @vdolez I am trying with tagged outputs. But even then I am getting UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ''.  I am not even using Pickle in my code as well. I will just update the question with details

Comment: @SriHariSriHari.M maybe the UnpicklingError has to do with how you read your input. I'm not a Python expert but it seems to me there's a race condition issue...